# Display loop data based on other loop data laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I have table (**api_field**)
[image: (api_field)]
and table (**cs_question**)
[image: (cs_question)].

I just display data from column **field** in table **api_field** in some condition using this query in my controller :

```
 $fields = DB::table('api_field')->join('api_criteria', 'api_criteria.fieldId', '=', 'api_field.id')
                                       ->join('api_report', 'api_report.criteriaId', '=', 'api_criteria.id')
                                       ->join('borrower', 'borrower.id', '=', 'api_report.borrowerId')
                                       ->where('borrower.user_id', $id)
                                       ->get();
```

So, to display field data in blade, I use this code:

```
@foreach ($fields as $field)
  <td>{{$field->field}}</td>
@endforeach
```

And now, I want to display data from column **question** in table **cs_question** , based on **question_id** (**question_id** is equals to **field** column in table **api_field** ).
So, I use this php code in my blade :

```
<?php

$questionr = DB::table('cs_question')->join('api_field', 'api_field.field', '=', 'cs_question.question_id')
                               ->where('cs_question.question_id', $fields->field)
                               ->get();

foreach ($questionr as $questionrs)
        if($questionrs->question != null){
            $questionnya = $questionrs->question;
        } else {
            $questionnya = 'empty question';
        }                                   
?>
```

but there is some data in the column **field** that does not exist in column **question_id**. so, I display data in blade like this : {{$questionnya }} .and now the show is like this (supposed **blaed** & **urdob** not have a question) [image: result].

I wanted that did not have **question_id** such **blaed** & **urdob**, the result is "**empty question**", not "**Nama Ibu Kandung**" anymore like now.
I hope anyone can help me here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell you want to display "empty question" instead of this "Nama Ibu Kandung".

I think that the solution may be that the question is not null, but empty.

```
if($questionrs->question != null && !empty($questionrs->question) && $questionrs->question !== ''){
   $questionnya = $questionrs->question;
} else {
   $questionnya = 'empty question';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've try your code .. but it still give the same result

Comment: Anyway from where the text "Nama Ibu Kandung" comes from? In general it should display nothing. I think that you need to provide more code.

Comment: Nama Ibu Kandung should be Question of qsl_0002 . and urdob & blaed is empty in column question_id in  table cs_question

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer by hardcode in blade like this :

```
<?php
        if (strpos($fields->field, 'qsl_') !== false){
            $question = DB::table('cs_question')->join('api_field', 'api_field.field', '=', 'cs_question.question_id')
                        ->where('cs_question.question_id', $fields->field )->get();
          foreach ($question as $questions)
                $questionnya = $questions->question;
       }else{
                $questionnya = 'empty question';
       }
?>
```